# How can I make correlation of one columns variables based on their targets scores

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgnpe.png)As shown in the pictures, I have a **df** containing two-column **"mir"** and **"gene"**
I have also a correlation called **"mat"** containing scores for "gene" items which are targets in my df

imagine I have two mirs (hsa-miR17-5p and hsa-let-7f-5p) as shown in input 2. Their targets in the second column are (hsa-miR17-5p: "619279", "80380", "57169", hsa-let-7f-5p: "283659", "1763", "8091", "9480", "541565")So there are two sets of genes, I want to look at these sets of genes correlation score and based on them, find a score for their mirs, for example, the score between "hsa-miR17-5p" and "hsa-let-7f-5p" might be 0.8 out of 1 so they have a fairly strong connection. Imagine I have 2000 mirs so for all of them I have to do this function, as a result, find a correlation matrix for mirs ( concluded by their target genes scores)

[image: df]
dafa dataframe
[image: mat correlation]

[Input1: correlation of gene IDs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BYBc.png)

[Input2: mir and their corresponding gene IDs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3OyE.png)

[Desired Output: I A correlation of mirs based on their common targets and (gene IDs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLlFh.png)

Comment: Hey Reza, it would be really helpful if you share an example input and desired output for that example

Comment: What are the columns in `mat`? I presume the first column is gene ID.

Comment: Thank you Ori for trying t help me, I attach two input files example and one desired output:

Comment: Hi Reza, the question is still a bit unclear to me. Please explain the mathematical way of computing the expected output, and then we can help achieve it in pandas. It is unclear to me how the 2 inputs translate to the desired output.

Comment: Sure, imagine I have two mirs (hsa-miR17-5p and hsa-let-7f-5p) as shown in input 2. Their targets in the second column are (hsa-miR17-5p: "619279", "80380", "57169",   hsa-let-7f-5p: "283659", "1763", "8091", "9480", "541565")....... I want to look at these genes correlation score and find a score for their mirs, for example, the score between  "hsa-miR17-5p" and "hsa-let-7f-5p" is 0.8 out of 1 so they have a fairly strong connection. Imagine I have 2000 mirs so for all of them I have to do this function, as a result, find a correlation matrix for mirs ( concluded by their target genes scores)

Comment: @Reza it is better to update your question by adding your latest comment to your question